# CaseTeamMember not returned as a Child

Tags: apex, schema

When getting schema info for objects related to cases Case Team Member does not show up. Case Team Member has a lookup to Case so I would think the relationship would work. Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
parentDescribe.getChildRelationships()
```

Comment: I didn't know there was a `getChildRelationship` methods, that's nice. What API Version are you using? What Profile are you running as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed the following code in Execute Anonymous:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describe = Case.sObjectType.getDescribe();
for (Schema.ChildRelationship relationship : describe.getChildRelationships())
{
    system.debug(relationship);
}
```

and I found among the relationships the following:

```
Schema.ChildRelationship[
    getChildSObject=CaseTeamMember;
    getField=ParentId;
    getJunctionIdListName=null;
    getRelationshipName=TeamMembers;
    isCascadeDelete=true;
    isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;
    isRestrictedDelete=false;
]
```